# How to change custom field order in field group?

Tags: administrator, custom-field, sorting

For articles, I have created two custom fields and I have registered both in a field group -- this much is fine.

Now I would like to change the order in which the fields are displayed on the page. I didn't find a way to do it from the backend interface. The order seems to be related to the id of the fields.

Is it possible to do this from within the administrator interface or do I have to go into the database and manually modify the IDs of the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the fields in the field group is determined by the order the fields appear in the fields page. You can therefore use the up/down arrows on the left to drag and drop the fields in the order you want and they will be displayed in that order in your field group when displayed in your component.